# Why can't I see Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms version 10.0.0.0 in "Add Reference..." dialog?

Tags: reporting-services, reference, assemblies, reportviewer

I have a VS2008 Reporting Services project (database: SQL Server 2008 RC2). This project has been updated from VS2005/SQL2005.

I need to update the Report Viewer control to version 10.0.0.0. But when I install the Redistributable (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a941c6b2-64dd-4d03-9ca7-4017a0d164fd), it isn't added to the .NET-tab in the 'Add reference...' dialog!

I can see the Microsoft.ReportViewer 8.0.0.0 and Microsoft.ReportViewer 9.0.0.0 in the dialog, but no 10.0.0.0

I tried running uninstalls for everything ReportViewer related, and reinstalling the ReportViewer 10.0.0.0 control. But I still see both version 8 and 9 in the dialog, but no version 10!

Checking the GAC through Start->Run->Assembly I can see all three versions. I cannot remove 8 and 9 because they apparently are used by other programs...

This is driving me somewhat nuts...

What do I have to do to make this assembly available in the "Add Reference..." dialog in Visual Studio 2008??

Regards 
Alex

Comment: Is it properly installed in the GAC? What versions do you have there?

Comment: Using Start->Run->Assembly I can find the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms (10.0.0.0). I can find the 8 and 9 versions aswell. But only the 8 and 9 versions are listed in my 'Add references...' dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, found a solution: Apparently VS2008 combined with ReportViewer2010 requires a little handy-work:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changliw/archive/2010/06/29/use-the-reportviewer-2010-control-in-visual-studio-2008-project.aspx

After I extracted the assembly DLLs from the GAC, I could add them to the 'Add reference...' dialog as described here:

http://www.csharp411.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-visual-studio-add-reference-dialog/

I hope this'll help another distressed soul! ;)

/Alex

Comment: I added the reference to RV 10 into VS 2013 via browsing, as discussed at CSharp411.  References->Assemblies->Framework still only shows RV 9.

Comment: Oops, took too long to edit.  ReportViewer is under References->Assemblies->Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of assemblies not showing in Add reference is the implicit target framework filtering. E.g.: Visual Studio 2010, .NET Fwk 4.0 target will filter assemblies targeting this particular fwk. To add Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms 10.0.0.0, I changed project's target fwk to 3.5, added the references and then switched back to 4.0.