# Crystal Report : Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am not able to view crystal Report in visual studio 2017. when I am runing project on browser and trying to open report from Reports Tab I am getting  Error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can any one please tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.XmlSerializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494641/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-webforms-xmlserializers)

Comment: I install SAP crystal Reports developer version for visual studio 2017 now Reporting option is displaying in my visual studio. Should I need to install `Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008`  also

Comment: at very first I install report viewer but that time error was getting so I uninstall that. should I need to install again